# Find/Replace with Wild card in SQL Query

Tags: sql, xml

I have a hashed line of text that typically looks like this in column called configuration_xml in tbldatafeed.

```
<NetworkCredentialWrapper UserName="RANDOM_HASH_HERE" Password="Random_Hash_Here" />
```

I am trying to write a SQL Query that replaces that hash with a known entry and run the query which will rehash the value after the query is ran.  (Essentially I am force my own username/password in here so I don't have to keep reseting it 1000 times because I have many of these entries)

I was using

```
DECLARE @Password VARCHAR(100) = 'Password'
SET configuration_xml = replace(CAST(configuration_xml(max)),'HASH',@Password
```

but then I realized it hashes to different values each time which makes my Query useless

End States I'd like to be able to set the password through this query so I am not doing it by hand 100 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manipulate with XML instead of pure string.

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '<NetworkCredentialWrapper UserName="RANDOM_HASH_HERE" Password="Random_Hash_Here" />'
SET @XML.modify('replace value of (/NetworkCredentialWrapper/@Password)[1] with "Password"')
PRINT CAST(@XML AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
```

Comment: How does this work if the RANDOM_HASH_HERE is Random every time?